# which part of java allocates memory?

Tags: memory, jvm, allocation

Is memory allocated by JVM , & where all the data stored in RAM or Hard-disk. Or memory allocated by constructor, if yes then how memory allocated of static class members.?

Answer (score 0):

JVM creates a memory area called 'The Heap' on startup where all of the application memory goes. This is created in RAM and is garbage collected when full. See the Memory Management documentation for details -> [Understanding Memory Management](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, there are different kinds of allocations: object data (reference types) is stored in so called *heap*, primitive data and object pointers are stored on *stack*. Both stack and heap are in RAM, in a JVM process memory area.

Effectively, *object* allocations are done by constructor, or, more specifically, `new` call.

[This awesome article](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html) explains allocations in a more precise and correct way.